# How to use optimistic locking in my procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to use optimistic locking in Procedure upd_account,
 or I should use it in some other way

I do this as an exercise, in the task it is written that I pay attention to multiple use by the user, that more users can change values for the same acc_id.
and to look optimistic vs pessimistic locking and consistent read.

I can not find anything about consistent read.
Is it associated with optimistic locking?
how to use consistent read?
(or to make a new question)

I'm a beginner in Oracle

I am sorry if I did not explain well.

I am work in oracle 12c release 2

Thank you advance

I have package body and it look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS

        ...

      PROCEDURE upd_account
          (p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
            , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
            , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
            , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
        )
      IS
      BEGIN
           UPDATE accounts
            set acc_name = p_acc_name
              , acc_amount = p_acc_amount
              , acc_date   = p_acc_date
           WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
       COMMIT;
      END;
      ...

      end account_api;
      /
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not have this book, I will try to find this book.
you can send me some link on the internet about it.
or explain to me how to do this, I did not find anything

Comment: All reads in Oracle are consistent by default. Updates, however, are always on the latest version of a record; if another session has the row locked, it will block and wait until the other session either commits or issues a rollback. For a brief intro to optimistic locking, this may help: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2005/10/avoiding-lost-updates-protecting-data-in-a-multi-user-environment/

Comment: I read this, he explained how to use ptimistic lock with trigger, how to do it in the procedure?

Comment: In the assignment writes: I need to pay attention to the possibility of multi-user use and look for information about "pessimistic vs. optimistic locking", and "consistent read".
Maybe I did not understand what I should do

I do not know how to use "optimistic locking"

as explained here: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/OptimisticLocking.aspx but this is not pl / sql

Comment: @perica in the pemistic you lock the table with its specific data as for the optimistic you read the data first and when you want to update you make the data are the same then you do the updates. for example how to use optimistic you have balance account of 1000$ you want to add for example 200$ so youll update balace=1200$ ok ? lets say another user/applicatio at the same added 100$ then you update to 1200$ the balance is wrong because it should be 1300$

Comment: here it comes the locking either you lock this employee so nobdoy change anything in him , or you get his salary which is 1000$ and before you do the update you do check if the salary remains 1000$ if it still the same you do the update. is there something you need to explain ? @perica

Comment: The optimistic/pessimistic distinction only arises where you retrieve some data in one step and write it back in another, as then you have to cover the case where another session has changed it in the meantime. If you are simply issuing an `update` then the issue does not really arise.